# Android разрешение на запись для сериализации объекта

Tags: android, файловая-система, сериализация

Как сериализировать объект в андроид?
Делаю так:

```
//создаю файл для отправки объекта
final File file = new File(fileName);
//сериализирую объект в файл
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                order = new Order(serverPass, purchase.getText().toString(), 
new Date(), name.getText().toString(), logInEmail, null, null, null, 
listSelectNom, null, listSelectIt);
                oos.writeObject(order);
                oos.flush();
                oos.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("ошибка сериализации: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
```

Выдаёт ошибку: мол нет разрешения на запись.

```
I/System.out: ошибка сериализации: \tmp\order.dat: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

Что делать? В манифест добавил разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Но ничего не изменилось, как дать разрешение на запись? Или в android сериализация делается как то по другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не о сериализации вообще, вы не понимаете принципов файловой системы Андроид, запрашиваете разрешение на запись на внешний носитель, а сами пытаетесь записать что-то на системный раздел.

Вот этот материал поможет вам разобраться что куда писать можно.
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Как выполнить запрос именно на разрешение записи, я выполняю запрос на разрешение WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(что, вроде как является разрешением записи на SD), ну и если его нет, то запрашиваю его, а записываю то я во внутреннюю память. Не могу найти, какое именно разрешение мне нужно, как оно называется? В статье написано, что внутренняя память всегда доступна приложению, так почему же приложение выдаёт ошибку Read-only file system?

Comment: Так вы же пишете в `\tmp\order.dat`, а если внимательно читали, приложению доступны во внутренней памяти для записи только папки `getFilesDir()` и `getCacheDir()` и да, без дополнительных разрешений.